# How do I send baseUrl as a parameter with Cypress.io

Tags: cypress

I am researching switching from Protractor to Cypress.io. 
I have some tests up and running, however, I want to be able to send the `baseUrl` as a parameter as I can with Protractor.

I have tried:

`$ npm run cypress:open --config "baseUrl=myUrl"` --still uses the baseUrl from my config file.

`$ npm run cypress:open --env "baseUrl=myUrl"` --still uses the baseUrl from my config file.

and a host of other things, none of which work quite right.

I want to be able to pass a parameter to my command which gives me the flexibility to choose which environment I am running my tests in. I can do this with Protractor, with a command like this:

`$ ng e2e --suite testSuite --baseUrl myUrl`

What is the equivalent for Cypress.io?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to set the env variable `CYPRESS_baseUrl`

`CYPRESS_baseUrl=[your baseUrl] npm run cypress:open` should do it for you

Answer (score 14):

I think the correct way to do this is:

```
$ npm run cypress:open -- --config "baseUrl=myUrl"
```

Otherwise, the config parameter is passed to npm instead of cypress. Notice the extra `--`

Good luck!

Answer (score 10):

Brendan's answer is correct.
I would like to add that

```
$ npm run cypress:open --config "baseUrl=myUrl"
```

may not be working since you try to propagate some configuration into a command inside your package.json.
If instead you'd do for example:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --config baseUrl=myUrl
```

it should work just fine.

This is good to know since it will let you use additional CLI options as well (which you do not know ahead of time).

PS: *--env* wouldn't work for **baseUrl** since baseUrl is a built-in configuration value and not a regular env variable.

Comment: The correct way to call a pre-defined npm script with parameters is `npm run cypress:run -- --config baseUrl=myUrl` (note the extra `--`)

Answer (score 1):

What I did was simply:

```
export CYPRESS_BASE_URL=SOME_OTHER_URL
yarn cypress run
```

This will override the `baseUrl` configuration. See: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Overriding-Configuration

Answer (score 0):

I know this is somewhat old, and things have changed over time, but adding the following to package.json works for me (running local on 8080):

```
"cy:run": "npx cypress run --spec cypress/e2e/stt/* --config baseUrl=http://localhost:8080"
```

Then from command prompt run:

```
npm run cy:run
```

Obviously you could add several more entries to package.json referencing different servers (i.e. dev, stage, prod)